# UITableViewCell detailTextLabel area not allowing selection of cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Inside a `UITableViewCell`, the area covered by `detailTextLabel` doesn't recognise selection of the `cell`.

The cell style is `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`

The entire bottom area of the cell is not selectable and users are sometimes tapping the `cell` multiple times before tapping high enough on the cell for it to detect the touch.

I've tried `[[myCell detailTextLabel] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` or setting background colour to clear which has helped in similar cases, what else can I do?

I thought about adding a `UILabel` as a `subview` of the cell instead of `detailTextLabel` which I will try if I can't find the answer here.

EDIT - as requested

Here is the code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
    NSString *cellId = @"cell";

    locationsCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if(locationsCell == nil) {
        locationsCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    [[locationsCell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Optima-Bold" size:18]];
    [[locationsCell textLabel] setText:@"Choose your location"];
    [[locationsCell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Optima" size:14]];
    [[locationsCell detailTextLabel] setText:@"Tap to select"];
    [[locationsCell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return locationsCell;
```

EDIT
Sorry I've messed up. I had set a footer view for another table and it has added a clear footer view that made the cell un-selectable instead of adding a conditional for the two tables. I removed the footer and it's working.

Comment: can u show me cellAtRowIndexpath method code

Comment: why you are setting `[[myCell detailTextLabel] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` it must be YES

Comment: @preetam it was just one of the many things I've tried, I've also tried it with YES

Comment: ok..have you added `<UITableviewDelegate>` in .h file if you are not using default UITableviewController?

Answer (score 0):

Friend I tried myself what you are saying but for me it is working.
I tried simple code like this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"subtitle area text working %@ %d",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"indexpath row %d",indexPath.row);
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"working" message:@"yes" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```